# Node JS GET запрос: как получить данные в переменную?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Начинаю изучать Node.js

Возник вопрос: как отправлять гет-запросы и хранить ответы от серверов в переменной? Все примеры и уроки в Интернете показывают только как выводить их в консоль. Все мои попытки перехватить ответ в переменную не увенчались успехом, так как запрос асинхронный.

Может быть, я ошибаюсь, и есть рабочие примеры, но я таковых не нашёл... очень прошу ткнуть меня в них носом!

Спасибо!

Comment: ну ты хотя бы покажи свои попытки. Людям гадать, как и что ты там пытался реализовать. выложи пример кода

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6